# How can I print my tokens when using pyspark.ml.feature.Tokenizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, token, apache-spark-ml

I would like to look at the tokens that were created when I used pyspark.ml.feature.Tokenizer. How can I do that? If I have this piece of code:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="SystemInfo", outputCol="words")
```

I tried to print the tokens using `print(vars(tokenizer))`, but of course that returns only the attributes.
The full code can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-ipython-notebook-machine-learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform and show, that is it. Here is a quick example to guide you. I hope it helps.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 'Hello and good day'),
    (1, 'This is a simple demostration'),
    (2, 'Natural and unnatural language processing')
    ], ['id', 'sentence'])

df.show(truncate=False)
# +---+-----------------------------------------+
# |id |sentence                                 |
# +---+-----------------------------------------+
# |0  |Hello and good day                       |
# |1  |This is a simple demostration            |
# |2  |Natural and unnatural language processing|
# +---+-----------------------------------------+

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words")
tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df)

tokenized.select('words').show(truncate=False)
# +-----------------------------------------------+
# |words                                          |
# +-----------------------------------------------+
# |[hello, and, good, day]                        |
# |[this, is, a, simple, demostration]            |
# |[natural, and, unnatural, language, processing]|
# +-----------------------------------------------+
```